Pie chart is cutting off in Vaadin v24, when we zoom in/out
Implemented Pi Chart using Vaadin v24, here when I zoom in/out Pie chart, it's cutting off. Can anyone help me?
Whenever I zoom-in/zoom-out Pie chart should be appropriate (full circle) only in all scenarios.
Searched in different ways but couldn't find possible solution.

Could you provide a code example that demonstrates the issue?

As Jonte said it would be good to have some code examples for us to reproduce your issue, potentially some video/screen recording showing the problem.
Also maybe the best way to get some help (if you have a way to reproduce your issue) is to fill up an issue ticket in the relevant GitHub repository.
In this case here is the relevant GitHub:

https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3Avaadin-charts+


You can use the vaadin-charts label (as I filtered the results in the above link as well). Also I did not see, spot any similar issue in the list, so feel free to create one. Thanks!
